# Is there a way to format alternating lines (not paragraphs) without tables?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got a bunch of code I want to present clearly, and since code paper is practically impossible to get now I'd like to format alternating lines to improve legibility. It's easily done in a table, of course, or at a paragraph level with a lot of manual work, but is there any way of doing it *per line* and without using tables?

Tried to add an example, but my office computer has decided it doesn't like loading pages any more. So hey, I'll improvise...

Any way of getting a per-line banding without resorting to manual line breaks?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdjrS.jpg]

Comment: Is each line an actual paragraph, in that it has a paragraph mark at the end of the line, or is each line terminated with a carriage return?

Comment: Each line of code is a paragraph, but because they often get quite long they tend to break over. I'll add an example.

Comment: Might I suggest using numbers at each line, the way it is in many IDE editors, than using different BG colours? Or you may screenshot the code in your IDE editor and paste it in Word, the way how I used to do this in my university to keep the readable format in my IDE when I submit a report to my professors. :)

Comment: It's all Excel VBA, so there's no line highlighting or numbering anyway. :-D

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a couple of paragraph styles and using a small VBA routine to apply them to the currently selected text, e.g.

```
Sub applystripestoselection()
' create paragraph styles called banded1 and banded0
' with the characteristics you want
Const StylenamePrefix As String = "banded"
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Selection.Paragraphs.Count
 Selection.Paragraphs(i).Style = StylenamePrefix & CStr(i Mod 2)
Next
End Sub
```

If you need to be able to *re-apply* to numerous separate blocks in the document, I suppose you could do that by bookmarking the blocks in some way - e.g. use a name such as "codeblock" and append the next number every time you insert a new bookmark, to give you codeblock1, codeblock2, codeblock3 etc., then modify the above VBA to apply the styles to every paragraph in every range "covered" by a codeblock ref. Then you'd probably still have to do a bit of manual sorting out (Undo can be your friend at this point!)